# How do you test for Zero documents in Firestore

Tags: firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a database where the user submits items.

When it is the first item submitted I need to do another computation.

I need the equivalent of

If (RecordCount() == 0) from Dart and Firebase.

When I do a

```
int len = await Firebase.instance.collection('paid')
   .where('userPaidAmount', isGreaterThan: 0).getDocuments()
   .documents.length 

if (len == 0) 
   // process the user has not paid
```

It "Awaits" with a console message "asyncronous suspension"

How do I test for "no data" in the database?

There must be a way.

Comment: So actually you want to know if the `paid` collection contains any documents, right?

Comment: You have to actually execute the query, as you would normally.  You can't avoid awaiting an asynchronous operation.

Comment: @DougStevenson my question though is, I execute the query and there are ZERO documents to return, then I know the user' has not paid. 

How do you wait asyncronously for the result set is equal to Zero? 

How do I say the listener is done, or how do I set it for Zero Document returns is equal to continue. 

In the calling logic I call the function. 

if (userHasaid(userId, documentId)

Comment: @AlexMamo I actually want to know 

if (paid collection contains no documents) then 
  makePayment();

Comment: It sounds like you need a realtime snapshot listener, not a single fetch.  There are examples of that on the main doc page for the module.  https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore

Comment: @DougStevenson my question though is, I execute the query and there are ZERO documents to return, then I know the user' has not paid. 

How do you wait asyncronously for the result set is equal to Zero? 

How do I say the listener is done, or how do I set it for Zero Document returns is equal to continue. 


This function actually is called from a parent where I have an Await. 

amountPaid = await userPaidAmount(userId, InvoiceID) 
if (amountPaid > 0) 
   Allow  proceed 
else 
  Payment Gateway 

I'm picking two different routes based on information in the database.

Comment: @DougStevenson I'm listening for Zero Documents 

if DocumentCount = 0 
  // do payment 
else 
 // do buy

Comment: That is not a listener, that is a one-time fetch. Look at the link and see the code samples that use StreamBuilder.

Comment: @JamieT You should do what Doug advised you to do.

Comment: @DougStevenson so I use a StreamBuilder to get a single does not have any documents instead of using a query? Have you seen an example where the user wants to get Zero Documents, I couldn't find one.